# selecting ringtone from sd card android

Tags: android, android-notifications, ringtone

In my android app I added code for selecting the notification tone from built in tones .But I need to add one more option that to select songs from sd cards also. Also better to add conditions for selcting music files only. Please help me.I am giving the codes in my app

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Tone");
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri) null);
        this.startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
        return true;
    }
@Override
     protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent intent)
     {
         if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 5)
         {
              Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);

              if (uri != null)
              {
                  this.chosenRingtone = uri.toString();
              }
              else
              {
                  this.chosenRingtone = null;
              }
                  DatabaseHandler1 dbtone = new DatabaseHandler1(getApplicationContext());
                    int count = dbtone.getRowCount_5();
                    if(count > 0){
                    dbtone.resetTables_5();
                    }
                 dbtone.addUser_5(chosenRingtone);
          }            
      }
```

I am setting the ringtone here

```
DatabaseHandler1 db2 = new DatabaseHandler1(context);
        int count = db2.getRowCount_5();
            if(count > 0){
         x =db2.getUserDetails_5();
        String temp =  x.get("tone");
                try{
                    notification.sound = Uri.parse(temp);
                    }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

                    }
            }
            else{
        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            }
```

Comment: is my answer is helpful to you...?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all media files

```
String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
        //your projection statement 
        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID
        };
        //query 
        cursor = this.managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                selection,
                null,
                null);


        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                songs.add(cursor.getString(0));
                songs.add(cursor.getString(1));
                songs.add(cursor.getString(2));
                songs.add(cursor.getString(3));
                songs.add(cursor.getString(4));
                songs.add(cursor.getString(5));
                album_id.add((long) cursor.getFloat(6));
        } 
        int a[]= new int[]{R.id.textView1 ,R.id.textView3};//, R.id.textview2};
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.items, cursor, new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,           MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST/*, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION*/} ,a);
                setListAdapter(adapter); 
    }
```

Comment: hope it helps you,if you are satisfied with the answer please close the question by marking it answered and all the best :)

Answer (score 0):

try this code it will help you to set song of audio file as ringtone :

```
File path = new File(path, "mysong.mp3"); // path is a file to /sdcard/media/ringtone

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, path.getAbsolutePath());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "My Song title");
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 215454);
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Madonna");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

//Insert it into the database
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(path.getAbsolutePath());
Uri newUri = main.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
  myActivity,
  RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
  newUri
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To search the external sd card for audio files, you can use the following code:

```
public ArrayList<File> findAllMP3s() {
    static File storage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    ArrayList<File> allFiles = new ArrayList<File>();

    recursiveAudioFinder(storage, allFiles);

    return allFiles;
}

public static void recursiveAudioFinder(File directory, ArrayList<File> data>) {
    if(directory == null) {
        return;
    }
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    for(File file: files) {
        // Grab audio files, write some filter to check if audio file
        if(file.isFile() && file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".mp3")) {
            data.add(file);
        } else if(file.isDirectory()) {
            // Recursive call to find files in sub directories
            recursiveAudioFinder(directory, data);
        }
    }
}
```

For this to work, the permission `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` must be added. Choose one of the files in the list, and set the ringtone using `RingtoneManager`